# Jquery Iframe remove all the elements except <table>

Tags: jquery, replace

I have, for example:

```
    <iframe width="700px" src="/top_list.html"></iframe>
```

How can I remove everything from this frame except table .. or how can users see only the table content from that page?

Comment: Can't you modify the iframe's content without using JavaScript? :|

Comment: Does the table in question have a unique qualifier (id, class name, etc)?

Comment: ok there is a <div class="main"> before table

Answer (score 0):

If there is no unique identifiers and you cannot change the top_list page you can use jquery .hide() to hide everything you do not want shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need a few jquery tools:

- http://api.jquery.com/contents/ contents to get the iframe contents
- http://api.jquery.com/next/ next to get the next element after `.main`
- Targeting the rest of the elements and hiding them.  Without a solid example, I'll do my best to demonstrate how it might be done

My example is very explicit on the queries.  No chaining, so you can see what's going on.  I hope it helps.

```
$(window).on('load', function() // wait for load event, so the iframe is fully loaded in
{
  var $iframe = $('iframe'); // assuming only one?  You need to target the right iframe, perahps with iframe[src="/top_list.html"] if that's your only option

  var $contents = $iframe.contents();
  var $main = $contents.find('.main');
  var $tbl = $main.next(); // now we have the table

  $contents.find('*').hide(); // hide everything
  $tbl.show(); // show table and...

  var $parent = $tbl.parent(); // get/show all parents of the tbl

  while($parent.length)
  {
     $parent.show(); // show parent
     $parent = $parent.parent(); // move up the hierarchy
  }
});
```